# remove dots from bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I would like to remove dot from bibliography or even in some parts of doc. I would like to remove dot at end of the each sentence.

Thanks,
sree7k7

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which bibliography style do you use?

Comment: Can you please provide a [`minimal working example`](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) showing how you are building your bibliography?

Answer (score 1):

In the vast majority of `.bst` files the full stop at the end of a bibliography entry is controlled by the function `fin.entry` which typically calls the function `output.nonnull`. `output.nonnull` typically has a condition for (or calls a function that has) a `before.all` case where the relevant instruction is `add.period$`. A possible solution would be to replace `add.period$` by `" "`.